# How do I perform a stoppie in Saints Row: The Third on PC?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

How do I make a motorbike do a stoppie (reverse wheelie) for the challenge?

I've tried every key combination I can think of!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, stoppies are **not bound** to a key.  You can change this in the settings menu, though.

Comment: I'm a few hundred miles away from my desktop and my laptop can't run SR3 - if someone wants to edit my answer with steps to change the binding, please do :)

Comment: Tried it, and works! Thanks. Then I just plugged a controller in instead, seems easier :)

Answer (score 8):

There's not a single key to make a stoppie.  It's a multi-part "trick" you can do, and it's pretty easy.

First, get a motorcycle.  Most work fine, but the sport bikes and dirt bikes work best.  I prefer the Sandstorm, personally.

Get a little bit of speed going, and then brake while pushing "lean forward."  As you slow down, you'll go up on just front wheel of the bike.  On the PC with a mouse/keyboard, as Dave mentions, you'll have to bind "lean forward" to a key.  On consoles or with a controller, you push the left analog stick forward.

A wheelie is similar, but you want to accelerate while pushing "lean backwards." (or pulling back on the left analog stick)

Comment: It occurs to me that this is more of a console answer, and perhaps the asker is on a PC.  Apologies if this is the case.  Like Dave says, you'll probably have to bind "lean forward" to a key.  On the console, the throttle and movement controls are on different fingers.

Comment: Any ideas where to find a dirt bike? Finding it tricky with a Kaneda!

Comment: According to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkomKNCvcgQ) there's one parked between the highway and the airport.  I found them to be pretty common, though.